# ComboBox styling in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a problem with a `ComboBox`. I wanted to change its apparency by overriding its style, but I have some problems of appearance, and I can't find where are they.

My `ComboBox` has this appearance:

[image]

I have two problems:

1. I don't know where to change the foreground of the expandable menu... Wherever I change it, it remains white!!
2. When I choose an option, the `Text` of the `ComboBox` appears twice, one in dark blue and one in white, as you can appreciate on the image. And I don't know how to change it...

My style looks like this:

```
<!-- All ComboBox styles -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border
          x:Name="Border" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          CornerRadius="5"
          Background="{StaticResource DarkGradient}"
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="1" />
        <Border 
          Grid.Column="0"
          CornerRadius="5,0,0,5" 
          Margin="1" 
          Background="{StaticResource TextBoxBrush}" 
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
        <Path 
          x:Name="Arrow"
          Grid.Column="1"     
          Fill="{StaticResource TextBoxBrush}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="DarkGray" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- ComboBox TextBox -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- ComboBox style -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
     <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/> 
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton 
                    Name="ToggleButton" 
                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                    Grid.Column="2" 
                    Focusable="false"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" /> 
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                        Style="{x:Null}" 
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        Focusable="True" 
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Visibility="Visible"
                        Foreground="DarkBlue"
                        IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/> 
                    <Popup 
                        Name="Popup"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        AllowsTransparency="True" 
                        Focusable="False"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid 
                          Name="DropDown"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                Background="{StaticResource TextBoxBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
           Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/> 
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If anyone can help to solve this, will be really appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I could solve the problem of writing twice the value by changing this:

```
Text="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
```

And then adding to the `ItemSource` selection sentence, and then setting it by default, but I still have the problem of being not able to change the `Foreground` of the combo...

**EDIT2:**

I discovered one thing: when I create the list, I do this:

```
listPrecissions = new List<Precisions>()
```

Where `Precisions` is a class that I created with two strings. If I create it with a direct string:

```
listPrecissions = new List<string>()
```

and add the items, it has a black foreground. But have no idea why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question lacks the following styles `TextBoxBrush`, `SolidBorderBrush` and `DarkGradient`.

> I don't know where to change the foreground of the expandable menu... Wherever I change it, it remains white!!

Setting the `Foreground` property on the ComboBox seems to change it for me (with your styles applied).

> When I choose an option, the Text of the ComboBox appears twice, one in dark blue and one in white, as you can appreciate on the image. And I don't know how to change it...

`<ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite"` and `<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"` are responsible for displaying the current item for two different cases. First is the normal one, the second is when the `ComboBox` is marked as editable (`IsEditable="True"`). In your style the default for `PART_EditableTextBox` is Visible, so just set it to Hidden.

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
    Style="{x:Null}" 
    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
    Margin="3,3,23,3"
    Focusable="True" 
    Background="Transparent"
    Visibility="Hidden"
    Foreground="DarkBlue"
    IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
```